How Does Apache Hudi Perform Snapshot Queries
It's not really clear to me how does Hudi ensure efficient snapshot queries (see https://hudi.apache.org/docs/next/table_types/)
What I see in the .hoodie folder is just a timeline consisting of lots of commit files.
Each commit file contains just an information (metadata about location, fileid, etc..)
about the changes introduced by itself.
Let's say there are 1000 commit files and there are some records that were added in 2nd commit and then never updated and nothing was changed in the corresponding partition folder - so to provide a current data snapshot Hudi has to lookup all commits to obtain locations for all data files, is it right?
As I expected to see something like Apache Iceberg is doing - it's metadata file contains information about ALL data files for a given snapshot.
Could someone please explain.
Thank you


so to provide a current data snapshot Hudi has to lookup all commits to obtain locations for all data files, is it right?

not really. the file location are present in the metatata table. the snapshot queries will use the timeline in order to identify valid commits (also exclude invalidated). hudi does not need to store all files in a given snapshot thanks to the ordered timeline design.
note that timeline is archived (keep say 200 commits max), then snapshot queries are not possible before the last non archived commit. btw all files written before are then considered to be read in the sbapshot queries.
last concept: data is stored in file groups. only one commited parquet file of each file group is considered during queries.

Metadata table is optional. Specifically, Trino is not using it when querying. What I'm asking for how does it behave with just Hive Metastore for example and timeline. As I understood Hudi HAS to scan a whole timeline to provide you a current snapshot. Is it right?

Right in case of MDT this is the same method. Hudi get sthe file list from file system instead. BTW yes hudi scan the whole timeline reason the archive mecanism exists to not grow too much.

It's still not clear me how does it work.. I manually deleted all commits from the .hoodie folder (didn't delete parquet files) and then select all query produced nothing. But once I insert a new record and new commit is produced for only that 1 record and this commit is only referencing a new parquet file - when I make the select all query - ALL results are being returned. How is it possible?

When you rm all commit this is equivalent to archive all them. Uou have to keep at least one commit for hudi to work.what you explain is compatible with how i understand the process.

But how does it work really - scans all parquet files in a directory then? As commit only contains delta - a specific change. In my case just 1 record insertion.

As said:  Hudi get list of file either from mdt or by scanning filesystem. Then it uses the actkve timeline to filter out unreferenced files. Details in my answer

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Sorry, i already did my best
